# OkHttp : Not increasing overall speed according to thread's count

Tags: java, multithreading, okhttp

I have a problem using OkHttp3.

Basically my project creates around a 50 threads. These threads share the following Client:

```
private final OkHttpClient CLIENT = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false)
            .build();
```

Whenever a thread tries to download a web page through HTTP it executes the following code:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(someURLString)
            .build();
Call call = CLIENT.newCall(request);
try (okhttp3.Response okHTTPResponse = call.execute()) {
    // handling the downloaded page here
}
```

My problem is that when I increase my threads to 100 threads or even 200 threads, the overall speed remains the same. However, when I run my project 2 or even 4 times, my overall speed increases by x2 or x4 times.

By the overall speed I mean the average number of downloaded web pages per second.

As OkHttp3 documentation states, `execute` doesn't have a limit on the number of HTTP connections, but somehow it looks like my code is still bounded by some kind of a limit I'm not aware of.

One more thing, when I create 200 threads, I create a simple logging where a thread prints a logging message whenever it starts and finishes downloading a web page, I noticed that only threads with ids < 30 are actually printing logging messages meaning that the other threads aren't actually performing any task.

Also, from the above mentioned logging I managed to calculate the average time needed to handle one page, which was around 0.5 seconds per web page.

I'm running my program on a server with 36 cores and the internet speed is 1 Gb, so CPU speed and internet shouldn't be a problem.

Can anyone help me with this or point the problem in my approach?

Comment: 30 threads executing, CPU has 36 cores. Possibly only 30 of your threads are actually being concurrently scheduled by the kernel?

Comment: If that's the case, then why does the overall speed increase 4 times when I run 4 different instances of the same program? while it stays the same when I increase the number of threads by 4 times?